Ngrok Config file not reading labels
Currently trying to get my flask app to connect to my pythonanywhere web-app. I want to use the free domain ngrok provides in order to connect the 2 however I'm finding conflicting information on how to setup my YAML config file.
This version while does work , doesn't use the domain name as the endpoint.
version: 2
authtoken: [Redacted]
tunnels:
  my_tunnel_name:
    proto: http
    addr: 6666
    hostname: [Free Ngrok domain name]

This is the config file ngrok suggests.
version: 2
authtoken: [Redacted]
tunnels:
  my_tunnel_name:
    labels:
      - edge=[edge label]
    addr: http://localhost:666

When i try this way it runs also but still with a temp. ngrok url. Additionally the dashboard states the following message: "No tunnels with labels matching edge=[edge label] are online." which is obviously not the case.
Any help would be greatly appreciated XD
For the ngrok url to be the free domain instead of a temporary url.

Where is your flask app running?

Ensure that you have created in the Ngrok dashboard, your free domain.
Then edit ngrok.yml for the tunnel following the documented configuration option
to open a tunnel to the host on port 6666.
version: "2"
authtoken: <redacted>

tunnels:
  my-tunnel-name:
    proto: http
    addr: 0.0.0.0:6666
    inspect: false
    domain: xxxxx.ngrok-free.app

Finally, start the tunnel with the terminal command:
ngrok start my-tunnel-name --config ngrok.yml


Totally works , thanks a bunch :)
